# How to display string in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark scala. This is a simple code in which i am fetching a .csv file with three columns. I am using map and split transformation to split it. But I am not able to display it after using mkstring() also. I do not want to use mkstring function in the last line inside collect.foreach(). Please find the code and suggest me how to display the string values.

```
package test
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext``
import org.apache.log4j._

object practice2 {

def main(args : Array[String])
{
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[2]","sampleApp")
    val data = sc.textFile("C:/Hadoop/Materials/Module-5_Spark/Spark/TotalSpentByCustomer/customer-orders.csv")

    val rec = data.map(x => x. split(","))
    val rec1 = rec.collect.mkString(",")

    // rec.collect.foreach(array => println(array.mkString(",")))
    rec1.foreach(print)

}
}
```

Comment: use `rec.collect().foreach(s=>print(s.mkString(",")))`

Comment: That i have already mentioned in my code. But I do not want to use mkString in the final action line. How to display the value of rec1  as per my code?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention your spark version.

I suggest you to tell spark it's reading a csv :

```
val data = sc.read.csv(path)        
//or 
val data = sc.format("csv").load(path);
```

There are options to get column names from csv header, or set them yourself with data.df("col1", "col2).
then, I'm not sure why you want to display strings but the best way for a demo is to use .show() like so :

```
data.show(10)
```

Comment: I know the above lines you have mentioned to read csv file but my question is with my code how to display the rec1 data. Show command is not working the error is : value show is not a member of the string.

Comment: So you're probably not working with recent spark version where .map returns a dataset. you should probably convert your RDD to a DF instead of collecting it. When you collect data, you're actually sending all worker's data to driver, so it can return a scala list. In most cases, you actually don't want to send data to the driver. So just data.map(...).todf(...).show(...)

Comment: To be more clear: after .collect, you are no more in spark api. you are back to scala.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
 rec.collect.foreach(array => println("%s".format(array.toList)))
```

Hope this helps.